# Problems defining EventListener to ul List items in javascript

Tags: javascript, events, html-lists, listener

I'm adding list items in javascript to ul id 'showingDeck'. I want to initialize li class 'card', and to addEventListener that would then change the class (CSS formatting) of the list item when clicked.

```
for (var i = 0; i < shuffledCards.length; i++) {
    var ul = document.getElementById("showingDeck");
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.innerHTML = shuffledCards[i];
    li.className = 'card';
    document.getElementById("showingDeck").appendChild(li);
    document.getElementById("showingDeck").addEventListener("click", processClicks(li));
};
```

processClicks gets triggered 16 times without clicks, and no clicks get registered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## [Event Delegation](https://www.kirupa.com/html5/handling_events_for_many_elements.htm)

If you are adding `<li>` dynamically, then an event will never stick them. Tags must exist at page load in order for them to be registered. So you'll need to use **[Event Delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation)**.

- First get a tag that meets two criteria:

  1. Must exist when page loaded.
  2. Must be the ancestor (the parent or parent of parent , or so on...) of the tags you want clicked, hovered, etc.
- Next register said tag to an Event (BTW the ancestor tag can even be `document` or `window`, but it's recommended that you use them for Key Events or non-DOM Events)

  ```
    ancestorTag.addEventListener('event', callback);
  ```
- Whenever there's a registered Event fired on the ancestor tag or it's descendants (child of, or child of child, and so on,) a callback function will be invoked.
- It's during this time, the ancestor tag can now be referenced as [`event.currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) and more importantly, the tagged that was actually clicked, hovered over, erc... is now referenced as [`event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target).
- It doesn't matter if the tag has an `#id`, `.className`, student ID, or whatever because `event.target` will be that tag specifically (in that respect: `this`).

---

### Pros

- You only need one Event Listener for an unlimited number of tags
- issues with dynamically added tags are resolved
- No `#ids`, `.classNames`, birth certificates, erc. is needed to identify the clicked tag.

### Cons

- None which is why we should never use [on-event` attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers) or add event listeners to a hundred tags.

---

### Demo

```js
var list = document.getElementById('list');

list.addEventListener('click', callback);

function callback(event) {
  var clicked = event.target;
  var listener = event.currentTarget;
  if (clicked !== listener) {
    clicked.classList.toggle('active');
  } else {
    return false;
  }
  return false
}
```

```css
.active {
  color: gold;
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<ul id='list'>
  <li>ITEM</li>
  <li>ITEM</li>
  <li>ITEM</li>
  <li>ITEM</li>
  <li>ITEM</li>
  <li>ITEM</li>
  <li>ITEM</li>
  <li>ITEM</li>
  <li>ITEM</li>
  <li>ITEM</li>
  <li>ITEM</li>
  <li>ITEM</li>
  <li>ITEM</li>
  <li>ITEM</li>
  <li>ITEM</li>
  <li>ITEM</li>
</ul>
```